# Can you force Oracle pl/sql client_host call to be modal?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

We are using Oracle Forms 10g client_host to copy a file to a temporary location, launch an application to view the temporary file, then delete the temporary file.  In this case the viewing application is Windows Internet Explorer.  The problem is that the delete_file call to delete the temporary file is called before IE can be launched to display the file, resulting in an error in IE because it can't find the file. The following is a code snippet showing what we are doing:

```
-- Copy the file to the site defined temporary location
client_host ('cmd /c copy '||Vcurrentfile||' '||Vtempfile);  

-- Launch viewing application and display the temporary file
client_host (Pviewer||' '||Vtempfile);  

-- Delete the temporary file
Vsuccessind := webutil_file.delete_file (Vtempfile);
```

Client_host is SUPPOSED to be modal, so the delete_file statement should not be executed until the user closes the IE window.  However, it appears that it is executed before the client_host call to launch the viewer is completed.  Any ideas?

Comment: We discovered that the reason the file did not display in IE was due to the lack of file extensions in Oracle App Server configuration file mime.types. Once the extensions were added to mime.types, the file displayed properly.  We still have an issue that the temporary file does not get deleted after IE is closed.  Using Firefox or Chrome, the temporary file does get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

CLIENT_HOST is modal in relation to the forms applet. The forms application is blocked until CLIENT_HOST returns. Calling the IE with CLIENT_HOST does not block the application until the IE is closed. But this is because the iexplore.exe is a windows application.
A windows application blocks the caller until the event loop is entered. You can check this in commandline. Enter the call and you will get the prompt back very sone IE is displayed.

If you want to open a webpage, why don't you use WEB.SHOW_DOCUMENT?

**EDIT:**
Try calling the IE with cmd /C start /W "C:\Programme\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe".
The start /W block the caller until the windows application realy closes.

Answer (score 0):

I try the following - it works:
webutil_host.blocking('"c:\programme\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k -noframemerging '||:URL)

Look for "IE commandline parameter" for the description of these parameters.